# Why does JS allow object properties to be both "quoted" and non-quoted? Is there a difference?

Tags: javascript

Why does JS allow object properties to be both `"quoted"` and `non-quoted`? Is there a difference?

```
var object = {

    "firstName": "SpongeBob", //quoted
    lastName: "SquarePants"   //non-quoted

};

console.log(object.firstName); // -> SpongeBob
console.log(object.lastName);  // -> SquarePants
```

Comment: http://es5.github.io/#x15.12.1 for reference

Comment: non-dotty names and reserved keywords need to be quoted.

Answer (score 0):

Sure there is:

```
var obj = {
    "crazy-property!name": "some string"
    // crazy-property!name is an invalid property name without quotation marks
};

console.log(obj["crazy-property!name"]);
// can't do console.log(obj.crazy-property!name)
```